# PID of commands run as different user

Tags: bash, su, pid

While being a root, I want to start a service as a specific user and write its PID file. Minimal nonworking example:

```
if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then  
su myuser <<EOF 
sleep 30 &  
echo $! >mypid.pid  
EOF
fi
```

After execution file mypid.pid is empty, $! is empty too, but there is a process sleep for my user with assigned pid (obviously). I pressume it is because a new shell is spawned and somehow it does not track its history. Is there any way I can make it work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you feed the shell invoked by `su(1)` from a script, `$!` gets interpreted by the script calling `su(1)`. The way to prevent this is to escape `$!`, then `$!` does get fed to the shell invoked by `su(1)` and not the calling script:

```
if [ $UID -eq 0 ]; then  
su myuser <<EOF 
sleep 30 &  
echo \$! >mypid.pid  
EOF
fi
```